# Исключение javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed при запросе на сервер

Tags: java, android, https

При отправке запроса вот сюда https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/ 
вылетает исключение. Отправляю запрос с Android 5.1
Вот код:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("fg", "onClick");
                String URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + editTextId.getText().toString();



client.post(URL, new RequestParams(), new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                    Log.i("fg", "response: " + response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.i("fg", "response: " + responseString);
                }

            });
        }
    });

}
```

А вот что выводит в логах:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7f75d9c280: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-05 22:43:01.391 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0x7f76058888:0x00000000)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     ... 19 more
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-05 22:43:01.392 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7f75d9c280: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0x7f76058888:0x00000000)
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
10-05 22:43:01.393 2782-2895/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/System.err:     ... 19 more
10-05 22:43:01.394 2782-2782/com.colorblind.uncolor.cards W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], Throwable, JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received
                                                                        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                                                                            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
                                                                            at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
                                                                            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
                                                                            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
                                                                            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7f75d9c280: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                        error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0x7f76058888:0x00000000)
                                                                            at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
                                                                                ... 19 more
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема заключается в SSLv3, по которому андроид подключается по дефолту. Даже если на сервере отключен SSLv3. После того, как SSLv3 стал компрометируемым, все больше серверов отключают этот протокол, оставляя только tls.

Попробуйте соединиться через openssl:

> openssl s_client -connect site.com:443 -ssl3

скорее всего получите ошибку соединения. В то же время

> openssl s_client -connect site.com:443 -tls1_2

вероятно соединится нормально (ну или `-tls1` уж точно).

Чтобы решить проблему, необходимо удалить SSLv3 из доступных для связи протоколов для сокета. Делается это через оборачивание SSLSocket'а и переопределение `setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols)` с явным удалением из массива "SSLv3".

Добрый человек собрал проект с SSL фабрикой и выпиливанием SSLv3

https://github.com/gotev/okhttp-tlscompat

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вы правы. Вот что тест ssllabs.com выдал: (Protocols: TLS 1.3 Yes, TLS 1.2 Yes, TLS 1.1 Yes, TLS 1.0 Yes, SSL 3 No, SSL 2 No)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja по факту там DTLS, все верно надо пытаться найти вариант коннекта. Особенно весело, когда приходится соединяться с разными серверами на разных версиях андроида.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Вы сохранили пару моих дней :)

Answer (score -1):

мне вот это помогло, поищи в эту сторону

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)  
.tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
.cipherSuites(
      CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
.build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder() 
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

Comment: Автор OkHttp не использует.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja пусть использует